# How to get image size from URL

Tags: jquery

I am trying below code to get the image size in KB/MB/GB  (not width and height) from live URL. But it's not working.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('HEAD', 'http://www.2015autoblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/2015-Toyota-Land-Cruiser-Front.jpg', true);
```

debugger

```
alert(xhr.status);

if ( xhr.status == 200 ) {
    alert('Size in bytes: ' + xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
} else {
    alert('ERROR');
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this code it is working

```
var tmpImg = new Image();
tmpImg.src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"; //or  document.images[i].src;
$(tmpImg).one('load',function(){
  orgWidth = tmpImg.width;
  orgHeight = tmpImg.height;
  alert(orgWidth+"x"+orgHeight);
});
```

The above code will gets the image dimension.

For the file size: 
No, there is no way you can get the image size using jQuery or pure JavaScript. The only way is to get it from server side using ajax.

You can get the image url send it to a service or server side page and have the page or service return the image size.

Comment: Not height and width. i need size in KB/MB. like 1 MB etc.

Comment: Did you find any solution?